# ArrayList empty after being serialized only if not directly assigned

Tags: java, arraylist, reference, serializable

I am having trouble when sending/receiving a Serializable object that contains an ArrayList. I have a class Robot that looks like this:

```
public class Robot {
    private ArrayList<InstructionCard> pool;
    /*other fields... */

    public void refillPool(Deck deck) {
        int nCards = this.healthPoints - this.pool.size();
        if(nCards >= 1) {
            ArrayList<InstructionCard> cards = deck.draw(nCards);
            //we add the cards to the old pool
            for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
                this.pool.add(cards.get(i)); // A
            }
            //pool = cards;  //REPLACE THE FOR LOOP WITH THIS LINE DOES THE JOB
        }
    }

    public RobotInfo getInfo(){
       return new RobotInfo(this.pool);
    }
}
```

I use the information contained in a Robot object to create a serializable object RobotInfo, to be sent over a connection:

```
public class RobotInfo implements Serializable {
     private ArrayList<InstructionCard> pool;

     public RobotInfo(ArrayList<InstructionCard> p) {
         pool = p;
     }
}
```

When I receive such object, however, the pool is an empty ArrayList.
`InstructionCard implements Serializable` as well, and it only contains an int and a `String` fields.

I made some tests and I'm sure that just before sending the `RobotInfo` object its `pool.size()` is not `0`.

When I receive the message containing it, however, `pool.size() returns 0`, unless (and this is what I totally don't understand) I replace the for loop in the `refillPool()` method with a direct assignment.

I believe that I must be doing something wrong with `InstructionCard` references at point A (doesn't seem a `Serializable` related problem to me).

The real question is why the pool in `RobotInfo` is NOT empty before sending in both cases but becomes empty only if I use the for loop?

EDIT: I was able to make a temporary workaround replacing the `ArrayList<InstructionCard>` with `ArrayList<String>`, recreating it every time I need to send a RobotInfo object. This somehow makes me think even more that is simply some sort of reference issue.

Comment: if you use your loop (A), how do initialize the pool list so that is not null? Also instead of using a loop to add all elements you could just use the existing addAll method.

Comment: I omitted the constructor of Robot wich initializes pool to a new, empty ArrayList. Thanks for the addAll() tip. When I have problems I try to do everything I can "manually" to expose logical flaws

Comment: I put up a "guess" answer. If it doesn't work for you - spend some real time reading about [mcve] to then improve your question Dont explain in 10 lines what code is doing - try to come up with a *minimal* code example that results in the problem. If your understand/assumptions about your code would all be matching up with what your code does ... you would not be here asking us to help with that bug you got somewhere!

Comment: I totally agree with you, it's hard if not impossible to find something wrong with so little information about the code. If it wasn't for the lack of time I would love to write from scratch some tests to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am *guessing* here:

```
private ArrayList<InstructionCard> pool;
```

That **leaves** `pool` to be **null**.

So this code:

```
pool = cards;
```

would put a non-null reference into pool.

On the other hand; that would imply that `cards.size()` is actually `0`; as you would run into a `NullPointerException` here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++){
 this.pool.add(cards.get(i));
```